# How do I manually remove a nuget package for .Net MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm in the process of migration a XamarinForms 5 app to MAUI and the latest error I get is
`` The Java type `mono.android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat_OnActiveChangeListenerImplementor` is generated by more than one managed type ``

Searching online, so far I think it is because the app is using Android.Support.V4 when it should only be using AndroidX, causing the duplicate to be generated as AndroidX replaces Support.V4.

However I cannot figure out how to remove the Support.v4 package because the only reference to it is an implicit reference by an SDK which I cannot remove ( see screenshot below)

[image: Nuget package window screenshot showing AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4]

The project file (MAUI) only has these package references

[image: Project file package references screenshot]

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the package list as text. It makes it easier to search for the individual packages. You'll need to remove all incompatible packages and only use packages that are supported by MAUI. Not all packages for Xamarin have been migrated or have MAUI support, yet. This is especially true for third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question as I managed to figure out the issue after a solid several hours long session.

No packages needed to be removed. Somehow I had managed to install a version of
`Birdie.Plugin.FirebasePushNotification` from 2020 , instead of `Plugin.FirebasePushNotification', the current version.

The solution was to remove that old package and install the correct once which made the error go away.